# android version compatibilty

Tags: android, version

I have developed and Simple android application in Java and also uploaded it on `play.google.com`. I uploaded successfully and also published well and I made all steps to published and save the app.after publishing it is showing on app store.Problem is that when I searched the app on my android device then it give the error of "This item is not compatible with your device". I don't understand why this error is being occurred. Kindly any one tell me how can I make and android app which is compatible with all versions of android or any other method through which my app should sun on all android devices.

Here is my manifest file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="sml.sml.pkg"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SMLActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I just saw your updated post. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to provide android:minSdkVersion & android:maxSdkVersion in AndroidManifest.xml. 
i think your mobile version is not supported to the version you implemented in your project. So, in Androidmanifest file just follow the following changes as shown......

Androidmanifest.xml

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:maxSdkVersion="11"/>
```

provide those versions based on your mobile version also. if you are using android 2.2 means its API level is 8. so provide minSdkVersion as 8.

Comment: -1, why on Earth would you want to set `android:maxSdkVersion="11"` based on the information the OP has provided?

Comment: Sir I am Using Gingerbread 2.3 so what change should be for this version

Comment: Sir I set 9 but it shows this error "<uses-sdk> tag should specify a target API level (the highest verified version; when running on later 
 versions, compatibility behaviors may be enabled) with android:targetSdkVersion="?""

Comment: then provide minSdkVersion="8" and targerSdkVersion="10" because as you told that you are using Gingerbread 2.3 it's API=10.

Comment: Is there any change in my SDk require for API=10 ?

Comment: as the code you have provided change your android:minSdkVersion="10" & run it. if you are using API-15 means you need to check that SDK  supports the features which you used in your app.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of reasons why this might occur. Most likely you are either:

1. Not specifying the correct minimum SDK your application is compatible with. To do this, you should add to your `AndroidManifest.xml` the following.

   ```
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="#" />
   ```

   where the `#` should be replaced with the integer corresponding to the minimum SDK number your application supports. For example, if your application has features that are supported by Gingerbread (API 10) but *not* Froyo (API 8), then you should specify the number to be `10`. **Note that you rarely want to add the `android:maxSdkVersion` attribute, as this will prevent devices from using your application when new SDK versions are released.**
2. Your application uses a feature that is not supported by your device. This might be the case if you have declared in your manifest the `<uses-feature>` tag.

---

Edit:

I just saw the code you added to your original post. Your code, specifically, `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />`, will prevent Android devices running Android versions lower than 15 from using your device. To allow older versions to use your application, you'll need to lower this number. Make sure you are 100% certain that the SDK you choose supports 100% of the features that your application requires.

Comment: Sir I am Using Gingerbread 2.3 version so what change should be in my setting file or is there any way that my setting would be global for all versions of android.

Comment: If you want your application to work for Gingerbread (but not anything lower, i.e. Froyo), then you should use `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />`

Comment: and what to do for running my app on all kinds of versions ?

Comment: To allow older versions to use your application, you'll need to lower the number in the `minSdkVersion` attribute. Make sure you are 100% certain that the SDK you choose supports the features that your application requires.

Comment: Check out [**this article**](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/backward-compatibility.html) for more information.